# Where is the DefaultKeyBinding.dict file on a Mac

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Pro w/ OS X 10.9.3 installed.  I have read various pages that talk about adding custom keyboard mappings to the mac.  They all mention modifying a DefaultKeyBinding.dict file.

Where is that file?  I haven't been able to find it in Finder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to find this file. You just create it as an empty one, and put your custom keybindings in it.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/KeyBindings/
touch ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
open -e !$
```

Note that it's `Binding` without a plural S.

Some interesting/useful keybindings from a fellow Super User [are here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220060333/http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html).

Comment: In the link, `StandardKeyBinding.dict` is provided but when I open my `StandardKeyBinding.dict` in `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict`, I am getting a binary file. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Preference List dictioniaries can be saved as binaries or in XML plaintext. Both are interchangeable; see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html

Comment: wow, thank you for this:.... "Note that it's Binding without a plural S." Spent the last hour trying to figure out why it wasn't working!